# Get a sequence of UTF-8 characters in hex from a unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

Let's say I have a UTF-8 string:

```
u"Some String"
```

Now all I want is to take this string above and convert it into a string of UTF-8 characters but in hex representation, so it will look like this:

```
"53 6F 6D 65 20 53 74 72 69 6E 67"
```

How to achive this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build the string using `join` and `format` in a list comprehension, iterating on the characters and taking their code using `ord`:

```
s = u"Some String"

print(" ".join(["{:02X}".format(ord(c)) for c in s]))
```

result:

```
53 6F 6D 65 20 53 74 72 69 6E 67
```

notes

- works both Python 2 and 3
- if your characters have a code > 255, you may get identifiers with a size greater than 2, but it still works.

Comment: `s = u"спасибо"` results in `441 43F 430 441 438 431 43E`, I don't know if it's what the OP expects.

Comment: Me neither, but it's still ok considering that 1) it works and 2) the values don't fit into a 2-digit integer. UTF-8 must mean 0-255 range for the OP.